# How to structure public_html folder

Tags: php, html, url, url-routing, public-html

My project is currently accessible like that:

website.com/development/views/index.php

My question is should I use URL rewriting to hide /development and /views and put index.php in the main /public_html folder or get rid of the /development folder? The issue with that is there are a bunch files from my hosting provider in public_html, so I wouldn't want to mix it with my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst it is a matter of preference, the standard practice in most php applications, I have seen is to have the index.php file in the root folder.

Instead of this

```
website.com/development/views/index.php
```

Most developers would expect something like this

```
website.com/development/index.php
```

Folder structure:

```
development
        |
         ---views
         ---js
         --- css
         --- index.php
```

The index.php file should sit at the same level as your views folder.

Comment: Thank you. How can it be organised so that when users type website.com, they will automatically see the index.php, which is inside development, i.e. how to make /development the root folder, rather than /public_html which is by default?

Comment: In that case you need to set up virtual hosting, take a look at this if you're using apache server https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: I've already set up a shared GoDaddy hosting account.. it would really be an overkill for that situation... So, in case I don't do virtual hosting, it would be best to just put all my App files in the public html ?

Comment: You can read on Symbolic Links. I have no experience with GoDaddy.

Comment: Ok, for anyone interested, the solution is very simple. What I did is first removed /development, and second created an index.php file that sits in the root public_html folder and redirects to my views/index.php